# Can not select a child of a div with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am making some kind of Like/Dislike system, and I use jQuery to get a variable that I want to pass to an html `<a>` element.

When I use `alert()`, it alerts the result, but it doesn't want to print it into the `<a>` element, which means it doesn't select it.

I want this to work for every element(post). And it's also important that LIKE works fine for every different post.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foto').on("click", '.like',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("color","blue");
    var pid = $(this).val();
    var datastr = 'pid='+pid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "like.php",
      data: ({pid: pid}),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        $(this).children("a:first").html(result['ajax']);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class=\"foto\">
  <h2>{$pic['fieldtwo']}</h2>
  <div class=\"slikata\">
    <img src=\"{$pic['fieldone']}\" width=\"98%\" height=\"auto\">
  </div>
  <div class=\"dolu\">
    <form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
      <button type=\"button\" class=\"like\" type=\"submit\" value=\"{$pic['post_id']}\">
        Like
      </button>
      <button type=\"button\" class=\"dislike\" type=\"submit\" value=\"{$pic['post_id']}\">
        Dislike
      </button>
      <a>PRINT THE VARIABLE HERE</a> 
      <a>Comments({$ncom})</a> 
      <a>Posted by:{$pic['post_user']}</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you go inside the `$.ajax()`, the scope of `$(this)` changes. So you need to save the `$(this)` you actually want for later use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foto').on("click", '.like',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css("color","blue");
      var pid = $(this).val();
      var datastr = 'pid='+pid;
      var eFoto = $(this); // store it here
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "like.php",
            data: ({pid: pid}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(result){
              eFoto.find("a:first").html(result['ajax']); // use it here
            }
      });
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

You'll also want to use `.find()` instead of `.children()` since the `<a>` in question is more than one level down from `.foto`.

Thanks @yoshi

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work.. I am getting so mad :/ Thank you anyway

Comment: @jzippy are you sure your browser isn't caching an old version of the JS file?

Comment: I dont really know how to check that. I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: @jzippy You also need to use `find('a:first')` instead of `children()`. jQuery Docs "The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well." api.jquery.com/children.

Answer (score 0):

mopo922 is right, your context is lost when you pass a callback to $.ajax

You can try to bind the context, modify your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foto').on("click", '.like',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("color","blue");
    var pid = $(this).val();
    var datastr = 'pid='+pid;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "like.php",
      data: ({pid: pid}),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        $(this).children("a:first").html(result['ajax']);
      }.bind(this) //bind the current context to the callback
    });
  });
});
```